# Installing wireless modem, commands, connecting to internet, get packages

Tags: wireless, internet, dell, modem, inspiron

1. hi, im newbie in ubuntu 11.04. i
   installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my machine
   (dell inspiron 1564). my wireless
   adapter is dell wireless 1397 mini
   (broadcam). i found a driver package
   for linux in my device support site and downloaded it. it
   named
   (hybrid-portsrc_x86_32-v5_100_82_38.tar.gz).
   now i want to set it up in Ubuntu,
   note that i have no internet access
   in Ubuntu OS. how should i unpack
   and install this package contents? i
   read a lot of pages about my
   question but i couldent be success.
   tell me wich commands must i learn?
   how use commands? i just know a
   little (sudo,xvzf,cd...!)
2. some other packages i downloaded are
   (ubuntu-codecs-pack-10.10.tar.gz)
   and (broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0.tar.bz2)
   and (scanModem.gz). i exrracted
   codecs pack and found some .DEB
   files, by double clicking on each
   file "ubuntu software center" window
   appears and by click on install
   button i installed codeck(s). but it
   dont work... i cant play music or
   movie files.
3. (note: im an exprienced advanced
   "win" user)
4. poor english...!

Comment: can you atleast get to wired internet ?? Ubuntu has a valid support for broadcom. And building will require you to install more packages. to install deb files do `sudo dpkg deb_file`

Comment: You should open one thread per question, if they are independently. Else, it is hard to follow the advice and you can't accept different, helpful answers.

Comment: i can not get to wired internet right now.

Answer (score 2):

About 1 : I am also on Dell Inspiron and using 11.04 with the same wireless adapter. I didn't need to install anything to get the wireless connection going. The only important part is to setup the connection from the Networking icon on the panel at the top (11.04). When you click it the Edit connection appears. Under Wireless settings you might have to create a new connection, save it and then connect to it.

You might also want to try and connect via wire. That will ensure that all the updates get installed and the net is connected. Then you can try connecting in wireless mode.

About 2 : All the codecs that is needed for playing music, video can be installed when 11.04 is installed for the first time. We just need to select and choose the option to install them. Otherwise later also from the repositories (Ubuntu software center) one can install them.